# Short story about a modern nurse treating revolutionary war soldiers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This was a short story. Possibly in OMNI magazine, though it could have been elsewhere. Probably published some time in the 1980s.

Viewpoint character is a nurse in a special military camp, modern day, constructed near some sort of intermittent time warp.

At random intervals, soldiers from a Revolutionary War battle that took place at the site appear in our time. This appears to be a one-way trip, though later the nurse sees a soldier flee back into the field and disappear, presumably back into the past.

The nurse is part of the medical crew who takes care of the wounded soldiers until they are well enough to be interrogated by scientists and other special staff - she never sees them after they leave the hospital tents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["The Battle of Long Island"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64188), a novelette by [Nancy Kress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Kress), first published in [*Omni*, February–March 1993](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59827+c). I haven't seen it myself so I'm not sure how well it matches the description.

This is from a review by [Steven H. Silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_H_Silver) at [SF Site](https://www.sfsite.com/06a/bt153.htm) of [Barry N. Malzberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_N._Malzberg)'s anthology [*The Best Time Travel Stories of All Time*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35927+c):

> While the ideas in Nancy Kress's "The Battle of Long Island" are intriguing, they are blunted by the disassociated voice of the narrator. Kress looks at a wormhole which opens between the Battle of Long Island during the Revolutionary War and the modern day. Her protagonist, Susan Peters, is an army nurse who tries to treat the wounded soldiers who occasionally fall through the Hole, eventually having to deal with the fact that the Revolutionary War opening of the Hole appears to be moving through a variety of different time-lines. At the same time, Susan must come to terms with the unknowability of her own past.

The following quotation from the story is copied from Michael Main's [Time Travel Fiction](http://storypilot.com/tt.php?keywords=kress+long+island) site:

> They're often like this. They find themsleves in an alien, impossible, unimaginable place, surrounded by guards with uniforms and weapons they don't recognize, and yet their first concern is not their personal fate but the battle they left behind.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!